# recursive question in python, n tower problem

Tags: python, recursion

In this question we will solve the n-towers problem. In the problem a square board is given. The row and column numbers in the table are counted from 0.
Each square can have a single tower. Distance between two towers is the minimum number of moves required to move one tower to the place of the other. One move of a tower will be defined as moving the tower to one of four
The squares next to it: above, below, right and left (the tower cannot be moved diagonally).

In the n-towers problem, we are given a non-negative integer d and a square board with n rows and columns, and we must place n towers so that:

1. There will be only one tower in each row.
2. The distance between any two towers will be greater than d.
   d is called "threshold distance".

The representation of the board and the location of the towers in the question: We will represent a square board of size n*n using a list of length n. The value at index i of the list represents the column where the tower is placed in the i-th row of the board.
For example, board = [0, 2, 4, 0, 2]

hey, I managed to do section A and B, but have difficulty with C:

Section A:
Implement the function (col2, row2, col1, row1(distance) which calculates the distance between two towers placed in the squares
(col1, row1 (and (col2, row2). It can be assumed that the input is correct.

Section B:
Implement the function tower_add(col, row, d, board) which receives a list board representing the board, a number d representing the threshold distance, and two numbers representing row row and column col in the board. The function will return the boolean value True
If a tower can be placed in a slot (col, row) so that its distance from any tower located in one of the rows above it is large
Right from the threshold distance d. Also, to the extent that the tower can be placed, the function will place the tower on the board. That is, the function
Place the value col in the row cell of the board list. If a tower cannot be placed, the function must return the value
Boolean False without changing the list.

Section C:
Realize the recursive function (d, n(towers_n) which receives a square panel size n and a threshold distance d. The function will return
A list of length n that represents some solution to the n-towers problem with a threshold distance d. If no solution exists, the function will return
empty list It can be assumed that the input is correct.
Recommendation (not mandatory) - for simplicity, you can define a starting board with n towers located in the column at index 0. That is
define an initial list that represents a table with zeros on which the changes will be made in the implementation of the function.
Examples:

1. For the reading (2, 6(towers_n), a possible list that will be returned is:
   [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4]
2. For the call (6, 6(towers_n) the empty list will be returned:
   []

```
def distance(row1, col1, row2, col2):
    dist_col = (col1 - col2)
    dist_row = (row1 - row2)
    # we want to return a non-negative distance
    if dist_col < 0:
        dist_col = (-1) * dist_col
    if dist_row < 0:
        dist_row = (-1) * dist_row
    return dist_col + dist_row



def add_tower(board, d, row, col):
    for i in range(row):
        if distance(row, col, i, board[i]) < d + 1:
            return False

    board[row] = col
    return True
```

Comment: So what's your question? What did you try? Are you thinking to solve the problem with a brute-force / backtracking algorithm, did you consider constraint propagation, ...?

Comment: I'm trying to solve it with backtracking algorithm ans to use the first 2 functions

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to use 2 sub functions for this task, as written bellow:

- The *solve_n_towers* function tries to place a tower in each row of
  the board, starting from the top - This is the main function that
  goes through each row.

  ```
  def solve_n_towers(n, d, board, row):
      if row == n:
          return board
      return try_column(n, d, board, row, 0)
  ```
- It calls the *try_column* function for each column in the current
  row, trying to place a tower in that column.

  ```
  def try_column(n, d, board, row, col):
      if col == n:
          return []
      if add_tower(board, d, row, col):
          if solve_n_towers(n, d, board, row+1):
              return board
      board[row] = 0
      return try_column(n, d, board, row, col+1)
  ```
- If a tower can be placed in the current column, it recursively calls
  *solve_n_towers* for the next row.
- If *solve_n_towers* returns a valid solution (i.e. a list
  representing the column position of each tower) - return *board*
- If *try_column* went through all columns without finding a valid
  solution, it backtracks by removing the tower it had placed in the
  previous column and moves on to the next column. (you can do it by
  board[row] = 0 for instance)
- Finally - if *solve_n_towers* went through all rows without finding a valid
  solution - return [].
- Env func *n_towers* calls *solve_n_towers*:

  ```
  def n_towers(n, d):
      board = [0] * n  # Create nXn board.
      return solve_n_towers(n, d, board, row = 0)
  ```

Hope this helps.